# FabricJS Group selection / bounding box after child resize

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm making a flowchart editor with FabricJS and I'm having troubles with my group bounding / selection box and/or the positioning of the child withing. I'm not sure what's happening.

My items are a `fabric.Group` (activity) with a `fabric.Rect` and `fabric.Text` inside it. The problem occurs when I change the text and want to change the size of the `Rect` with it. The text is changed from outside the `canvas`, so not with `IText`.

It works like this:

```
for(var i in finly.dossiertypes.workflow.activities ) {
    if( finly.dossiertypes.workflow.activities[i].activityId === activityId ) {
        var activity = finly.dossiertypes.workflow.activities[i];
        var rect = activity._objects[0];
        var text = activity._objects[1];

        /**
         * Set text
         */
        text.set({
            'text': name
        }).setCoords();

        /**
         * Get width from text object
         */
        var width = text.width + (finly.dossiertypes.workflow.activityPadding * 2);

        /**
         * Set rect width
         */
        rect.set({
            'width': width
        }).setCoords();

        /**
         * Caculate group bounds
         */
        activity._calcBounds( true );

        break;
    }
}
```

What happens is that the `rect` is shifting to the right outside the selectable group bounding. As you can see, the mousepointer suggests where the group is. The right side of the `rect` is not selectable, since it is outside of the `group`.

[image: Rect shifting to right]

I've tried several things, like setting the width of the group. Could anyone help me with this one?

Comment: check [addWithUpdate](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html#addWithUpdate)

Comment: @Durga addWithUpdate updates the group when adding a new object. I am not adding a new object. I am changing the text and then want to resize the `rectangle` with it, which is in the same `group`. This works, but resizing the group accordingly aswell without dispositioning the rectangle and text is the problem. I guess I could remove the `text` and then add a new one with `addWithUpdate` if that solves the problem.

Comment: Yes you can use [removeWithUpdate](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html#removeWithUpdate),and after updating the object add to group using addWithUpdate

Comment: I've fixed the problem by giving both `group` and `rect` property `originX: 'center'`